# Efficient algorithms for identifying the diamond fork&join vertices and the diamond pairs in directed acyclic graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-algorithms, dag

Given a DAG (directed acyclic graph) $G=(V,E)$ without *multiple edges*, i.e., edges with the same source and target vertices, we define:

A vertex $v_j \in V$ is a diamond-join ($\Diamond_J$) vertex if there exists some other vertex $v_f \in V$ *such that* there are at least two *vertex-disjoint* paths (except $v_f$ and $v_j$) from $v_f$ to $v_j$.

Furthermore, we call such a corresponding vertex $v_f$ above a diamond-fork ($\Diamond_F$) vertex. And, we call such a pair $(v_f, v_j)$ above a diamond ($\Diamond$) pair.

---

***An Example:***
In the figure below,

- $E$ and $F$ are $\Diamond_J$ vertices.
- $A$ and $C$ are $\Diamond_F$ vertices.
- $(A,E), (A,F)$ and $(C,F)$ are $\Diamond$ pairs.

[image: diamond-dag]

---

***The problems are:***

> 1. How to identify all the $\Diamond_J$ vertices?
> 2. How to identify all the $\Diamond_F$ vertices?
> 3. How to identify all the $\Diamond$ pairs?

The algorithms should be as efficient as possible. For example, are there linear algorithms, i.e., in $\Theta(n + m)$, for them, where $|V| = n, |E| = m$?

---

***My Thoughts:***

The first problem is easy: Run DFS on $G$ and the vertices pointed to by ***cross edges*** are the $\Diamond_J$ vertices.

I do not know how to solve 2&3 efficiently.

---

***Edit (2016-05-11):*** I accept the answer by @Chao Xu which solves the third problem in $O(nm)$ (I think it is correct; please peer review it). I am still open to possibly more efficient algorithm for the third problem, like $O(n+m)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G=(V,E)$ is the graph we work on.

Problem 2: $\Diamond_F(reverse(G))=\Diamond_J(G)$, where $reverse(G)$ reverses all the edges of G.

Problem 3:
This can be solved in $O(nm)$ time. For each vertex $s$, find all the pairs $(s,v)\in \Diamond$ in $O(m)$ time. To do this and split every outgoing edge $(s,v)$ with a new vertex $v'$. Namely, delete edge $(s,v)$, and replace it with $(s,v')$ and $(v',v)$. Find the [dominator tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)) with source $s$ in the new graph, which can be done in [linear time for dags](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=22166).

$(s,v)\in \Diamond$ iff $v$ is the children of $s$ in the dominator tree and $v\in V$.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with the concept of "dominator tree". I have to check it carefully. Two minor questions here. First, "find the dominator tree for $s$": do you mean that $s$ is the entry node when computing such a dominator tree? Second, "$(s,v) \in \Diamond$ iff $v$ is the children of $s$ in the dominator tree": do you actually mean $v$ is a child of $s$ in the dominator tree *and* $v$ is not a direct child of $s$ in the original graph $G$?

Comment: @hengxin I have made an update. One need to split the edges coming out of $s$.

Comment: Can you clarify which vertices should have their outbound edges "split"?